# Does google admin sdk have an API that allows you to add resources through CSV import?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I want to call the API of the admin sdk to create a resource function in my system.
Does google admin sdk have an API that allows you to add resources through CSV import?

Comment: I would need more information to be able to help you: What resource would you like? What is your use case?

Comment: I want to create buildings resource and calendar resource。

Answer (score 0):

I there is not an endpoint to do that.

What you can do is to use a Google API Client library ([see the official ones](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library)) to interface with it, so you can use a library in your preferred language to read the CSV and then use one of that clients to add it to Google servers.